# Google Tag Manager and property per language in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a multilanguage site and my plan is to track every language apart. 
Example:

```
domain.com

domain.com/en/

domain.com/de/

domain.com/fr/
```

For now, I have one GA Property and one GTM Container for the whole site. I was thinking of creating multiple Properties in GA for every language and one for all together. So that would look like this:

```
domain.com -> GA-1

domain.com/en/ -> GA2

domain.com/de/ -> GA3

domain.com/fr/ -> GA4
```

Now in GTM I would add to the container one Tag for each Property and create a trigger for each property. GA-1 trigger fires on all pages, GA-2 trigger fires on some page views that page path contains /en/, GA-3 trigger fires on some page views that page path contains /de/...

Is this the best practice and would this work like this? or is there another method to achieve this goal? Or is it enough to create some Views in GA and create some filters for each language?

The goal is to track every language in a different property so the starting point is always the language. Maybe there are also different conversions in the properties.

Comment: Best practice would probably to set the tracking id via a lookup table depending on the property and then simply fire the GA tag at the "all pages" trigger (provided they share a similar configuration. If not you could do property specific GA settings variables and again choose them via a lookup table). I have no idea if GTM configuration is actually on topic since you do it without coding yourself. Somebody should probably do a meta SO question on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, the best practice is to only have a single GA property that tracks the whole site. If you then want to only report on the data from a specific section of your site (i.e. a specific language) then you would use GA views (and filters) to achieve this. You would filter based on the Page dimension (e.g. Page starts with /fr).

There is no benefit to creating a property for each language except maybe to prevent you from going above the 10 million hits per property per month limit of the free version of GA. On the other hand, there is a benefit to tracking the entire site in a single property. The main benefit is that it allows you to perform cross-language analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add another solution to your question, where you can actually get the result you're asking for (even though it's not best practice).

If you go to **Variables** > **User-Defined Variables** -> **New**

Let's give the variable a name like *UA - Tracking ID*

You can choose variable type **RegEx Table**

Set the **Input Variable** to *{{Page URL}}*

And set the rows you need to the following:

**Pattern**

^/en/.*

^/de/.*

^/fr/.*

**Output**

*GA-2*

*GA-3*

*GA-4*

Under **Advanced Settings**

Check **Ignore Case**, and uncheck **Full Matches Only** and **Enable Capture Groups...**

Now add this variable *{{UA - Tracking ID}}* in your Universal Analytics tag under **Tracking ID**.

This will work on the tracking for each language.

When that's done, I will just add an extra **Universal Analytics** under **Tags** that tracks all the pages with the tracking ID GA-1.

Now two tags will be fired on eg. domain.com/en/, one for the combined domain GA-1 and one for the separate domain, in this example GA-2.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to handle Universal Google Analytics in a context where I use Wordpress, a plugin called WPML for translations, and a different domain per language. This saved me. Thank you!